# Arrangements with at least one digit corresponding to its position

Tags: combinatorics

I found the following question:

> How many 5-digit codes are there between 00000 and 99999 inclusive, having at least one of the digits corresponding to its position (for example, the first digit 1, or the second digit 2, and so on).

I originally thought of subtracting the number of arrangements without any of the digits corresponding to its position (i.e. 1 is not the first digit, 2 is not the second etc) to give $10^5 - 9^5$, but that results in arrangements with all five correct.

I then thought of doing: one digit is correct, and the others are not, hence $9^4 \times 5$ as there are five positions of the correct digit, and then proceeding from there.

But I'm wondering if there is a faster way?

Comment: Your first approach was correct. The number of such $5$-digit codes is indeed $10^{5} -9^{5}$.

Comment: I thought I was correct too, but the question is worth six marks, which makes me think that $10^5 - 9^5$ is too easy and hence an incorrect solution.

However, working through the second way also gives the same answer.